# Correct way to execute SQL Query like Select * from @database_name.dbo.table1

Tags: sql-server

i've declared my database name and need to execute it in a query so i don't have to type the name every time. It looks like this:

```
DECLARE @db_source varchar(255), @db_target varchar(255)
SET @db_source   ='database1'
SET @db_target   ='database2'
```

--Now i want to insert value into @db_target by select data from a table in @db_source

```
Insert into @db_target.dbo.table1 (field1,field2)
select (field1,field2) from @db_source.dbo.table1
where <some conditions>
```

-- but I got error everytime i execute the query
-- how to fix it?

Comment: Please include your error message

Comment: thank you for your respons, the error rise like this "Server: Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 39
Line 39: Incorrect syntax near '.' It looks like i miss the correct way on the syntax FROM @db_source.dbo.table1

Comment: SQL Server is declarative by design and does not support macro substitution.  This leaves dynamic SQL

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using dynamic SQL:

```
declare @SQL varchar(8000)
set @SQL = '
Insert into ' + @db_target + '.dbo.table1 (field1,field2)
select (field1,field2) from ' + @db_source + '.dbo.table1
where <some conditions> 
'
execute (@SQL)
```

Comment: `QUOTENAME(@db_target)` and `QUOTENAME(@db_source)`